# What is the difference between Ruby win32api and win32ole?

Tags: ruby, windows, api, winapi, win32ole

A piece of ruby code using `win32ole`

```
require 'win32ole'
ie = WIN32OLE.new('InternetExplorer.Application')
ie.visible = true
ie.gohome
```

Some code using `win32api`

```
require "Win32API"
message = "This is a sample Windows message box generated using Win32API"
title = "Win32API from Ruby"
api = Win32API.new('user32', 'MessageBox',['L', 'P', 'P', 'L'],'I')
api.call(0,message,title,0)
```

First one opens up internet explorer and the second one displays a message box.
Simply saying both seems to be able to access the OS and make it do stuff. Is win32ole a subset of win32api or is it the other way around? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*win32ole* is for interoperating with libraries & applications that have been written to act as OLE/COM servers, see [What is COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748355/what-is-com) for an explanation of that technology.

*win32api* interacts with the operating system API (Win32) which is also where OLE/COM are implemented, but *win32ole* exists to conveniently abstract away much of the complexities involved in making use of COM via its lower level API.